What is causing blender to crash when joining meshes
I am using 4.1 stable and I noticed this morning when trying to create a ring with multiple mesh objects that when I try to join the objects to one for 3d printing blender crashes. I typically use Ctrl J to join meshes but I also tried Boolen Union (ctrl shift numpad +). Is there some setting I had set wrong in blender to prevent joining meshes?  The objects don't have any modifiers on them


Worked fine here when joining all the objects to 'rounded Band' in one go. Select All, deselect the camera, Shift-select the band then Ctrl-J. (Blender 4.1.1)

Interesting doing it all in one go also just worked for me...but when I try to do it in parts it crashes

I can confirm, doing it piece by piece makes my Blender crash as well. Honestly I do not think this is a matter of "doing it wrong", because if you use a tool incorrect it should only give no result or not the desired result. Crashing should not be Blender's answer to an incorrect use... I would understand it if it would require too many resources that it crashes, but I do not think this is the case since joining all at once works...? I would rather file this as a bug report. In my test, joining two objects always works. Then selecting another and trying to join with the previous, it crashes.

But it seems to be a problem with the objects. Appending them all in a new file makes Blender crash as well whenever you try to make a second Join operation. But it is not a bug in 4.1.1 itself, joining more than once works in a new file with new objects.

I think the problem is from trying to join multiple objects that had modifiers applied to them. I was able to join 10 cubes piece by piece but 10 cubes that I applied modifiers to caused blender to crash


Download latest experimental Blender from https://builder.blender.org/download/daily/
Don't load previous settings.
Try doing the same with the least amount of off-topic steps.
Still crashes = report as a bug. Blender must NEVER crash (Blender devs see every crash as a bug)

If it's not too much of a problem, try disabling all the non-default addons that you have and try replicating the issue in a fresh file.
Overall, this really sounds like a bug. Don't forget to report.
